# Get remote registry value

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have the below script that I want it to go out to multiple servers and get the value of a registry. Unfortunately it is currently just posting back the local registry value of the machine that I am running the script on.

How do I get the script to run against remote registry?

SCRIPT:

```
clear
#$ErrorActionPreference = "silentlycontinue"

$Logfile = "C:\temp\NEWnetbackup_version.log"

Function LogWrite
{
    param([string]$logstring)

    Add-Content $Logfile -Value $logstring
}

$computer = Get-Content -Path c:\temp\netbackup_servers1.txt

foreach ($computer1 in $computer){

$Service = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "Name = 'NetBackup Client Service'" -ComputerName $computer1

    if (test-connection $computer1 -quiet) 
    {
            $NetbackupVersion1 = $(Get-ItemProperty hklm:\SOFTWARE\Veritas\NetBackup\CurrentVersion).PackageVersion

            if($Service.state -eq 'Running')
            {
                LogWrite "$computer1 STARTED $NetbackupVersion1"
            }
            else
            {
                LogWrite "$computer1 STOPPED $NetbackupVersion1"
            }
    }
    else 
    {
        LogWrite "$computer1 is down" -foregroundcolor RED
    }
}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can try using .net:

```
$Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $computer1)
$RegKey= $Reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Veritas\\NetBackup\\CurrentVersion")
$NetbackupVersion1 = $RegKey.GetValue("PackageVersion")
```

Comment: Thanks - this works; how do I incorporate this into the LogWrite that I want the value to be outputted to the logfile I have?

Comment: @lara400 As you 're doing in your code: `LogWrite "$computer1 STARTED $NetbackupVersion1"`. But maybe I didn't understood your question...

Comment: If you want to set a value, use `$RegKey= $Reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Veritas\\NetBackup\\CurrentVersion",$true)` then `regkey.setvalue("Name","Myvalue")`

Comment: Is there an option on this to invoke it using a specific credential?  Looks like it expects the current credential to have sufficient permissions.

Answer (score 15):

Try the [Remote Registry Module](http://psremoteregistry.codeplex.com/), the registry provider cannot operate remotely:

```
Import-Module PSRemoteRegistry
Get-RegValue -ComputerName $Computer1 -Key SOFTWARE\Veritas\NetBackup\CurrentVersion -Value PackageVersion
```

Comment: oh I didn't know this existed! neat-o

Comment: @shaylevy You did a great job with this module!

Comment: Thanks guys, glad you liked it :)

Comment: @ShayLevy, The link https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=psremoteregistry does not host MSI or zip for install. Do you have another link for download? Thanks.

Comment: @ShayLevy, Found that it is now available through `PowerShellGet` at https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSRemoteRegistry/1.0.0.0

Comment: For those of you reading this thread, this module was unpublished from the gallery. I did see the following module that was based on a fork of Shay's work
[PoshRegistry](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PoshRegistry/0.0.2)

Answer (score 6):

If you have Powershell remoting and CredSSP setup then you can update your code to the following:

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Computer1 -Authentication CredSSP
$NetbackupVersion1 = Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock { $(Get-ItemProperty hklm:\SOFTWARE\Veritas\NetBackup\CurrentVersion).PackageVersion}
Remove-PSSession $Session
```

Comment: If you have remoting and don't want to use third-party modules, use this. It's much easier to read than direct method calls. Is CredSSP a double-hop thing? I didn't need it for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

another option ... needs remoting ...

```
(invoke-command -ComputerName mymachine -ScriptBlock {Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\VanDyke\VShell\License -Name Version }).version
```

Answer (score 2):

For remote registry you have to use .NET with powershell 2.0

```
$w32reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$computer1)
$keypath = 'SOFTWARE\Veritas\NetBackup\CurrentVersion'
$netbackup = $w32reg.OpenSubKey($keypath)
$NetbackupVersion1 = $netbackup.GetValue('PackageVersion')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need user's SID and browse remote HKEY_USERS folder, you can follow this script :

```
<# Replace following domain.name with yours and userAccountName with remote username #>
$userLogin = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount(“domain.name“,”userAccountName“)
$userSID = $userLogin.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])

<# We will open HKEY_USERS and with accurate user’s SID from remoteComputer #>
$remoteRegistry = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey(‘Users’,”remoteComputer“)

<# We will then retrieve LocalName value from Control Panel / International subkeys #>

$key = $userSID.value+”\Control Panel\International”
$openKey = $remoteRegistry.OpenSubKey($key)

<# We can now retrieve any values #>

$localName = $openKey.GetValue(‘LocaleName’)
```

Source : http://techsultan.com/how-to-browse-remote-registry-in-powershell/