# PowerShell to get Computer name and .Net Framework for Domain computers?

Tags: powershell

I have this PowerShell script that get's .Net framework version from computer. I also need to apply "Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem" to this script to have both, computer names as well as .Net framework version. How do I go about this?

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * | ForEach { Get-ChildItem ‘HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP’ -recurse | Get-ItemProperty -name Version -EA 0 | Where { $_.PSChildName -match ‘^(?!S)\p{L}’} | Select PSChildName, Version } | Export-csv C:\temp\Netversion.csv
```

Comment: This seems to be the same question as your question from yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39113247/powershell-to-get-net-framework-version-from-ad-computers

Comment: That was the issue I fixed by myself. Now i wanted to add extra function to the script to get the computer name so that I can identify the .net framework version on all computers. So it's not the same question if you read carefully. If you can't help just check the next question and don't bother under voting my question.

Comment: @Samk80 The SO social contract is [be nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice), so I'd advice against making snappy comments even if you feel frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the computername from registry, so no need for `gwmi` call at all. (WMI calls are slow, so it's preferable to avoid those if possible.) The computer name is stored in `HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName`, so amend the script to read it too from the registry.

That being said, the script looks like it expects you to read *remote* computer information, but it is only reading the *local* computer. And it does that as many times as you have AD computer objects too. That's because it never uses the objects that are passed from `Get-ADComputer` to the pipeline.

What you would need is [remote connections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15069578) to multiple registries by leveraging the pipeline like so,

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * | ForEach {
    $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $_)
    $regKey= $Reg.OpenSubKey(<foo>)
    $value = $RegKey.GetValue(<bar>)
    # Do stuff with reg values, save in, say, collection of custom PSObjects
}
...
# Save the data into a file
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. People like you are like gems to this world.