# How do you keep track of changes in registry using powershell?

Tags: ruby, powershell, scripting, registry

I have a ruby script that basically checks for few keys in registry that are flags for our application. The script would check if the flag was 'on'(DWORD value 1) for longer than 14 days, it will turn it off(0) and send out an email.

To track this, what the script does is during the first run, it creates a local DB and store the flag name, date time and so on of every flag that is on in the registry. During next run, it checks this DB to find if the flag has been on for more than 14 days.

I wanted to know if there is a better way to handle this using powershell or should i create a local DB and follow the same flow?

### Further info:

So i will have different accounts under '\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Company\Clients' and each client will have a debug folder which will have the flags as seen below

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Company\Clients
                                        \Client1\Debug
                                                    IsEmail
                                                    IsShip
                                        \Client2\Debug
                                                    IsEmail
                                                    IsPack
```

So i need to effectively iterate through each client, maybe create an XML/JSON or DB with the client name, flags defined and current date time. Then during a later run, i should be accessing this info, compare the registry entries and turn off flags that have been turned for longer than a days specified. I will use the timestamp saved early for this.

### Update 1:

Few updates based on my updated understanding of how  powershell scripts work. I will have a master array or sort with a list of flags i need. For examples $MasterFlagList=['IsEmail','IsShip','IsNew']. Now during my first run of the application, i would like to create a json string like @tukan mentioned in this answer or xml file that will be something like:

```
<xml>
<Client1>
    <IsEmail>
        <value>1</value>
        <time>*current time*</time>
    </IsEmail>
    <IsShip>
        <value>1</value>
        <time>*current time*</time>
    </IsShip>
    <IsPack>
        <value>0</value>
        <time>*current time*</time>
    </IsPack>
</Client1>
<Client2>
    <IsEmail>
        <value>0</value>
        <time>*current time*</time>
    </IsEmail>
    <IsShip>
        <value>0</value>
        <time>*current time*</time>
    </IsShip>
    <IsPack>
        <value>0</value>
        <time>*current time*</time>
    </IsPack>
</Client2>
</xml>
```

So basically what happens here is that the XML string will have all the flags from masterlist, but if there is an entry for those in registry, that value will be loaded(0 or 1) and for those not mentioned in registry, default value of 0 will be set.

Next time i run, i will load this XML from directory into an object and for each client, i need to check if the XML already has a record, if so check the date time and see if the flag has been on for an amount of time, if so turn the flag off.

A better solution to implement the idea is also welcome. I am new to powershell and that why i thought of this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is really a nasty hack.  Why don't you store the date also in the registry with the client record?

I think Powershell does better job in querying registry than ruby.

To get values from a registry path:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\company\Clients\Client1\Debug
```

This yields result:

```
IsEmail      : 0
IsShip       : 0
PSPath       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\company\Clients\Client1\Debug
PSParentPath : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\company\Clients\Client1
PSChildName  : Debug
PSProvider   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
```

Alternative is to do it this way:

```
Get-Item -Path Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\company\Clients\Client1\Debug
```

Which gives:

```
    Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\company\Clients\Client1


Name                           Property
----                           --------
Debug                          IsEmail : 0
                               IsShip  : 0
```

If you want get the value directly, you have to do it this way:

```
(Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\company\Clients\Client1\Debug -Name IsEmail).IsEmail
```

To set a value (don't forget that you probably need admin rights for that!):

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\company\Clients\Client1\Debug -Name 'IsEmail' -Type Dword -Value '1'
```

### Now to the core of your question (and probably where you have problems)

I had to test it as i had different solution on my mind so it took quite a while.

```
# %Y ... year
# %m ... month
# %d ... day
# %R ... 24 hour time and minutes
# %S ... seconds
# example output: 20180226_10:38:23
$time_stamp= Get-Date -UFormat "%Y%m%d_%R:%S"
Write-Output $time_stamp

Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\company\Clients' -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $regkey = (Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath)

    $regkey.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
      # you could filter it via -> If($_.Name -like 'Is*'){
        # $regkey is a HashTable
        # Printing some output so you can check
        Write-Output $regkey.PSParentPath
        Write-Output $regkey.PSPath
        Write-Output $_.Name ' = ' $_.Value
        Write-Output ''
        # convert to JSON - will contain more information than you need -> format it as you wish
        $convert_registry_to_json = $regkey | ConvertTo-Json
      #}
    }
}

# Printing JSON output
Write-Output $convert_registry_to_json
```

Any further filtering or formatting I leave to the discretion.

**Edit**  - edited question 
This made me remember why I hate XML :).  I have create a simple solution to your formatting.  This code just a proof of concept, I recommend using functions to shorten your code (also avoiding duplicity)

```
$time_stamp= Get-Date -UFormat "%Y%m%d_%R:%S"

$result_hash = @{}
$result_array= @()
$first_level_hash = @{}
$second_level_hash = @{}

Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\company\Clients' -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $regkey = (Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath)

    $regkey.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
        # a HashTable
        #Write-host $regkey.PSParentPath
        $parent_key = $regkey.PSParentPath -Match '\w+$'
        #Write-host "Found Parent:" $matches[0]
        $parent_value = $matches[0]
        #Write-Host $regkey.PSPath

        #Write-Host $_.Name ' = ' $_.Value
        #Write-host ''
        $hash_key = $_.Name
        $hash_value = $_.Value

        If ($hash_key -like 'IsEmail'){
            $second_level_hash.Add('value',$hash_value)
            $second_level_hash.Add('time',$time_stamp)
            $first_level_hash.Add($hash_key,$second_level_hash)
            $result_hash.Add($parent_value,$first_level_hash)
            $result_array += ($result_hash)

            $second_level_hash=@{}
            $first_level_hash=@{}
            $result_hash=@{}
        } ElseIf ($hash_key -like 'IsShip'){
            $second_level_hash.Add('value',$hash_value)
            $second_level_hash.Add('time',$time_stamp)
            $first_level_hash.Add($hash_key,$second_level_hash)
            $result_hash.Add($parent_value,$first_level_hash)
            $result_array += ($result_hash)

            $second_level_hash=@{}
            $first_level_hash=@{}
            $result_hash=@{}

        } ElseIf ($hash_key -like 'IsPack'){
            $second_level_hash.Add('value',$hash_value)
            $second_level_hash.Add('time',$time_stamp)
            $first_level_hash.Add($hash_key,$second_level_hash)
            $result_hash.Add($parent_value,$first_level_hash)
            $result_array += ($result_hash)

            $second_level_hash=@{}
            $first_level_hash=@{}
            $result_hash=@{}

        }
        #$convert_registry_to_json = $regkey | ConvertTo-Json
      #}
    }
}
#Write-Output $result_hash
#Write-Output $result_hash.Item('IsEmail').Keys
#Write-Output $result_hash.Item('Client1').item('IsEmail')

Write-Output $result_array

ForEach ($result in $result_array) {
    ForEach ($entry in $result.GetEnumerator()) {
        $first_level_name = $($entry.Value)
        ForEach ($second_level in $first_level_name.GetEnumerator()) {
            $second_level_name = $($second_level.Value)
            ForEach ($third_level in $second_level_name.GetEnumerator()) {
                Write-Host "$($entry.Name) -> $($second_level.Name) -> $($third_level.Name): $($third_level.Value)"
            }
        }
    }
}

# You can convert it to JSON
# FSpecifies how many levels of contained objects are included in the JSON representation. The default value is 2.
$convert_result_to_json = $result_array | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3

Write-Output $convert_result_to_json
```

The output now is, which can be easily converted to `JSON` or `XML` if you want :

Now it yields result:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Client1                        {IsEmail}
Client1                        {IsShip}
Client2                        {IsEmail}
Client2                        {IsPack}
Client1 -> IsEmail -> time: 20180226_13:31:58
Client1 -> IsEmail -> value: 1
Client1 -> IsShip -> time: 20180226_13:31:58
Client1 -> IsShip -> value: 0
Client2 -> IsEmail -> time: 20180226_13:31:58
Client2 -> IsEmail -> value: 1
Client2 -> IsPack -> time: 20180226_13:31:58
Client2 -> IsPack -> value: 0
```

with JSON format:

```
[
    {
        "Client1":  {
                        "IsEmail":  {
                                        "time":  "20180226_14:40:02",
                                        "value":  1
                                    }
                    }
    },
    {
        "Client1":  {
                        "IsShip":  {
                                       "time":  "20180226_14:40:02",
                                       "value":  0
                                   }
                    }
    },
    {
        "Client2":  {
                        "IsEmail":  {
                                        "time":  "20180226_14:40:02",
                                        "value":  1
                                    }
                    }
    },
    {
        "Client2":  {
                        "IsPack":  {
                                       "time":  "20180226_14:40:02",
                                       "value":  0
                                   }
                    }
    }
]
```

**Second edit**

As for the DB.  Perhaps the best solution would be to use Sqlite, check the technet wiki about it [PowerShell: Accessing SQLite databases](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30562.powershell-accessing-sqlite-databases.aspx)

Comment: Wow @tukan that is a very detailed answer. This is similar to the approacd i was trying out. Regarding adding time in registry, that is something i cannot do due the restriction in the application that creates these entries in the registry. I will update the initial question with few clarifications that i need from new understanding of powershell

Comment: i have updated the question. Thanks again for your detailed answer. Meanwhile i will try to make use if your answer :)

Comment: @AswinFrancis I'm glad you like it.  Don't forget to upvote.]. I don't like XML (try `ConvertTo-XML`) too much - it is really a pain to work with.  In the original question you gave option with JSON so I took the liberty to do it this way.  Maybe it would be easy to create a JSON and then XML from it.

Comment: JSON is also fine but is there any way to get it working as mentioned in the updated section of the question. I need to keep track of flag updates independently. The XML is just to give a rough idea of the kind of data i am expecting. I leave it to the experts to tell me which is the best way to handle this :)

Comment: @AswinFrancis I have update the answer based on your updated question.  Now it generates similar structure to your `XML`

Comment: @AswinFrancis I happy for that! (it took me longer than I expected) Please don't forget to mark it answered  - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: thanks a lot :) i will mark this has answer. I have few more queries that i think you will be able to guide me with so i can get a start. Is there any way i can ask you these?

Comment: @AswinFrancis thank you.  Well you can always create a new question and I'll try my best to answer it.  I did not yet use the chatting here at SO.

Comment: any reason you dint recommend using a class then create a list of that class and then just calling convert to json on that. Then I would have one file for each client with json in it. Something like below:
[
    {
        "IsOn":  true,
        "IsLocked":  false,
        "Name":  "Background",
        "Timestamp":  "\/Date(1517661180000)\/"
    },
{
        "IsOn":  true,
        "IsLocked":  false,
        "Name":  "Carrier",
        "Timestamp":  "\/Date(1517661180000)\/"
    }
]

Comment: @AswinFrancis no perticular reason.  I wanted to show the genesis of it all, so you could cherry pick on what you need.

Comment: how do i access registry of remote machines. Assume i have a list of server and i want to do the above operation on these servers. So i want to do 
Get-ChildItem $RegKey -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
   $regkey = (Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPath) | Where-Object { $_.PSPath -match 'debug' }}
on list of server

Comment: @AswinFrancis use `Import-Module PSRemoteRegistry` see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069130/get-remote-registry-value

Comment: for this i need to setup the module in the server where the script is run right? Is there no inbuilt way?

Comment: @AswinFrancis you could use .NET's `[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey` as is written at the link.

Comment: i am trying that but i am not able to loop through the registry keys. How do i replace 
Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\path' -Recurse | ForEach-Object {}
with the value from $reg.OpenSubkey($keyname)

Comment: @AswinFrancis this is quite different from your original question.  You should probably ask separate question as this drifts away.  Anyways, You can try `foreach ($subkey in $reg.OpenSubKey($key).GetSubKeyNames())`

Comment: thanks. Created new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49154280/how-to-iterate-through-remote-registry-keys-using-powershell