# How to iterate through remote registry keys using powershell?

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a powershell script that  goes through a list of name value pairs in a registry key and do some maniuplations. All of this happens inside the below foreach-object loop

```
Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PathA\pathB" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
       $regkey = (Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPath) | Where-Object { $_.PSPath -match 'debug' }
       if ($masterList.Contains($_.Name)) #Check if the reg key is in master list
            {
                   Set-ItemProperty -Path $regkey.PSPath -Name $_.Name -Value 1
            }
}
```

This works perfectly fine in my local machine. I have to do the same but on remote machines registry. How can i iterate through as seen above?

I have tried:

```
$Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $server)
$key="HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PathA\pathB"
foreach ($subkey in $reg.OpenSubKey($key).GetSubKeyNames())
{
}
```

But this will just return me the name of the registry folderand i am not able to iterate through it

Answer (score 3):

[Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6) should do what you want. Something like this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName DC1 -ScriptBlock {
Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PathA\pathB" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
   $regkey = (Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPath) | Where-Object { $_.PSPath -match 'debug' }
   if ($Using:masterList.Contains($_.Name)) #Check if the reg key is in master list
        {
               Set-ItemProperty -Path $regkey.PSPath -Name $_.Name -Value 1
        }
} 
}
```

Since you have $masterlist defined locally, you can use $Using:masterlist - see  [Remote Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-6)

You  should also considering using  [PSSessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pssessions?view=powershell-6)

Comment: Yeah that's interesting. A down vote with no explanation.

Answer (score 2):

What about this approach?

Should recursively get you all the subkeys at the remote computer && root_key:

```
Function remote_registry_query($target, $key)
{
   Try {
        $registry = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("LocalMachine", $target)
        ForEach ($sub in $registry.OpenSubKey($key).GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            $subkey = $registry.OpenSubKey("$($key)\$($sub)")
            ForEach ($value in $subkey.GetValueNames())
            {
                Write-Output $subkey.GetValue($value)
            }
            remote_registry_query -target $computer -key "$($key)\$($sub)"
        }
  } Catch [System.Security.SecurityException] {
        "Registry - access denied $($key)"
  } Catch {
        $_.Exception.Message
  }
}

$computer = "remote computer name"
$root_key = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PathA\pathB'
remote_registry_query -target $computer -key $root_key
```