# Unable to find 7 Zip on servers using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I am making a small script for uninstalling the 7 Zip software from my servers, for that I have to find the 7 Zip software and un-install using the script.

On some windows servers I am able to find the software however on many of them I am unable to find them although they are installed as I can see it from the appwiz.cpl.

I cannot use `Get-ItemProperty` remotely, as WinRM is not configured correctly in the environment. So being too lazy I am trying create a powershell script to find the 7 Zip software and uninstall it.

```
$servers= Get-Content "C:\Server.txt"
Foreach($server in $servers)
{
    $ZipSoft= get-wmiobject win32_Product | where {$_.Name -like "*7-Zip*"}
    $ZipSoft.Uninstall()
}
```

I have tried to find individually on those servers however it does not gives me the output even no errors, other installed software I can find using the above.
Any idea about this why I am not able to find it on those servers?

Comment: "I cannot use Get-ItemProperty as I need to run it on 100+ servers." - what do you mean by this?

Comment: Get-ItemProperty does not allow me to run on list of servers for that I have to use invoke-command for which I have to fix winRM issues on all servers. That's why I said I do not want to use Get-ItemProperty

Comment: Ah, gotcha! [You can still query the remote registry service without PowerShell Remoting though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069130/get-remote-registry-value)

Comment: Yeap I have this option as well, but I was wondering why my above script is not providing me the required information. Even when I try below command-let on a single server it does not provide me any information
```
get-wmiobject win32_Product | where {$_.Name -like "*7-Zip*"} 
```
Not sure what is wrong in here.

Comment: Probably because the application is registered under a different product name, like "7 Zip File Manager" instead of "7-Zip"? Query one of the servers for the full list and manually go through it to see if you can find anything related to 7 xip

Comment: Yes I tried the same, but no luck... I tried this for other software it's working. I tried with "*zip*", "*7*" and even with the vendor name "*igvor*" but did not find it anywhere. However when I check though GUI it is installed.

Answer (score 0):

The wmi class win32_product is slow and incomplete.  It may only list msi installs.  It also verifies every msi when it runs.

```
get-package 7-zip*  # powershell 5 only

Name              Version Source ProviderName
----              ------- ------ ------------
7-Zip 19.00 (x64) 19.00          Programs
```

Comment: But it is showing for few servers, but on most it's not providing the information, where I can see through GUI it is installed. Same version of 7 Zip is also installed on the servers. Also PackageManagement module needs to be installed on server inorder to use get-package command-let. But my query is for win32_Product.

Comment: Win32_product comes up empty for me.  Did you use an msi installer on some servers?  get-package comes with powershell 5.

Comment: I used Get-Package but says no package found :

```

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Package "7-Zip*"
Get-Package : No package found for  '7-Zip*'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Package "7-Zip*"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power...lets.GetPackage:GetPackage) [Get-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.GetPackage

```

Comment: Any other suggestions now on this... As when I ran get-package it also provided the same ourput.

Comment: I don't know.  Did you install it just by unzipping it on some servers?  Maybe just look for the exe.

Comment: I used the installation exe file to use 7 zip.